# Runtime error 1004 method add of object sheets failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a sheet in the workbook and this error is coming up. Any suggestions?

> runtime error 1004 method add of object sheets failed

```
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1))
    ws.Name = "Global OHS RA Form"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`. Set the opened worbook to a variable and use that directly.

Also I recommend to check if the file was opened properly and if the workbook is protected.

```
Do While MyFile <> vbNullString
    Dim OpenedWb As Workbook
    Set OpenedWb = Nothing  ' initialize because looping
    Set OpenedWb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

    If Not OpenedWb Is Nothing Then  ' check if file was opened properly
        If OpenedWb.ProtectStructure Then  ' check if workbook is protected
            MsgBox "Workbook is protected, cannot add worksheets."
        Else
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = OpenedWb.Worksheets.Add(Before:=OpenedWb.Sheets(1))
            ws.Name = "Global OHS RA Form"

            ' … your other code here
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "File could not be opened properly."
    End If
Loop
```